# how can I apply function if element has that attribute with value

Tags: javascript, html

I want that if svg has attribute `aria-label="Like"` then execute a function and if it doesn't have attribute `aria-label="Like"` then other function execute.
Can any one tell me that how can I select attribute with attribute value to execute function.

```js
        function fn() {
            var likebtn = document.querySelector('.fr66n .wpO6b');
            var unliked = document.querySelector('.fr66n .wpO6b svg[aria-label=Like]');
            var x = document.querySelector('#demo');

            if (unliked === true) {
                x.innerHTML = "has"
            } else {
                x.innerHTML = "not"
            }

        }
```

```html
    <span class="fr66n">
        <button class="wpO6b  " type="button">
            <div class="QBdPU ">
                <span class="intro">
                    <svg aria-label="like" class="_8-yf5 " fill="#262626" height="24" role="img" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24">
                        <path d="M34.6 6.1c5.7 0 10.4 5.2 10.4 11.5 0 6.8-5.9 11-11.5 16S25 41.3 24 41.9c-1.1-.7-4.7-4-9.5-8.3-5.7-5-11.5-9.2-11.5-16C3 11.3 7.7 6.1 13.4 6.1c4.2 0 6.5 2 8.1 4.3 1.9 2.6 2.2 3.9 2.5 3.9.3 0 .6-1.3 2.5-3.9 1.6-2.3 3.9-4.3 8.1-4.3m0-3c-4.5 0-7.9 1.8-10.6 5.6-2.7-3.7-6.1-5.5-10.6-5.5C6 3.1 0 9.6 0 17.6c0 7.3 5.4 12 10.6 16.5.6.5 1.3 1.1 1.9 1.7l2.3 2c4.4 3.9 6.6 5.9 7.6 6.5.5.3 1.1.5 1.6.5.6 0 1.1-.2 1.6-.5 1-.6 2.8-2.2 7.8-6.8l2-1.8c.7-.6 1.3-1.2 2-1.7C42.7 29.6 48 25 48 17.6c0-8-6-14.5-13.4-14.5z"></path>
                    </svg>
                </span>
    </div>
    </button>
    </span>
    <button onclick="fn()">call fn</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector()` returns the element if the selector finds a match, or `null` if it doesn't. It never returns `true`, so `unliked === true` can never succeed.

Use `if (unliked)` instead of `if (unliked === true)`. A DOM element is always truthy, while `null` is falsey.